# Step definition on cucumber is not finding path on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, cucumber

Working with Ruby on Rails and I'm writing step definitions so that I can run cucumber.  However, I have a general def that visits a page and cucumber cannot find the path I gave it:

```
Can't find mapping from "the Brainstormy home index page" to a path.
```

This is the step definition:

```
Given /^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name)
end
```

And here is the Scenario:

```
Scenario: Sign up for Brainstormy

Given I am on the Brainstormy home index page
When I fill in "firstName" with "John"
And I fill in "lastName" with "Adams"
And I fill in "email" with "jadams@gmail.com"
And I fill in "email2" with "jadams@gmail.com"
And I fill in "password" with "spot1234"
And I fill in "password2" with "spot1234"
And I press "Sign Up"
Then I should be on the profile page
```

My routes:

```
home_index        /home/index(.:format)     home#index
root              /                         home#index
```

My routes.rb:

```
root :to => 'home#index'
resources :ideas
resources :users

#root :to => redirect('/home/index')
match 'home/index' => 'home#index'
match 'users/new' => 'users#new'
```

The thing is, I didn't write the definition.  I got it from a working app and basically mirrored what they did.  Can someone help me sort this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look inside the `path_to` method. This will be some sort of mapping from human readable strings to URLs. You will have to add a mapping for `"Brainstormy home index page"` to go to whatever URL you want. If you need additional help, include the `path_to` method in your post.